# Function.length is not the same as this.length. Why?

Tags: javascript

Here's the simple function that expects three agruments. It is possible to get the expected number of arguments either via `arguments.callee.length` or `myFunc.length`. Why `this.length` returns 0? Shouldn't `this` and `myFunc` refer to the same function object? I'm a bit confused :).

```
function myFunc(a, b, c){
   console.log(arguments.callee.length, myFunc.length, this.length);
}

myFunc("a","b"); //=> prints 3 3 0
```

Comment: Why did you think `this` refers to the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A function's `this` keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode. In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the bind method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called, and ECMAScript 2015 introduced arrow functions whose this is lexically scoped (it is set to the this value of the enclosing execution context).[[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)]

**In your scenario:** `this` belongs to owner of the `function` we are executing or to the `object` we are invoking a method of.*(how a function is called)*

In your example, owner of `myFunc` is `window`(`window.myFunc("a","b");`) hence `this.length == 0`. If you open `window` object in console, you will find `length` property which is having value as `0`.

---

To have your own `this` argument while invoking the `function`, Use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), *The `call()` method calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided individually.*

```js
function myFunc(a, b, c) {
  console.log(arguments.callee.length, myFunc.length, this.length);
}
myFunc.call(myFunc, "a", "b"); //=> prints 3 3 3
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my mind is obviously kind of clouded today, should have thought of that in the first place :), thx!

Comment: It happens mate! I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: The explanation of *this* is not very accurate and is presented as a quote with no attribution. A function's *this* is not the function "owner", it's a value set by how the function is called, use of *bind* or lexically in arrow functions.

Comment: @RobG, You can(_should_) edit it to make it valid...The term _owner_ represents _How the function is called!_ for example, `foo.bar()` => `foo` is the owner.. I do agree with the `bind` but I though it will add confusion.. Thank you..

Comment: There is also *new*,  *apply*, *call* and not setting *this* at all (so it defaults to the global object or undefined in strict mode). Better to reference [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) or a suitable question on SO.